# Separate MVC application as a folder using Handler Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

We have a legacy webforms app and a new section of our site developed with MVC. It works a treat as an application in the Default Web Site in IIS.

Only downside is that the root site's session object isn't passed to the application. We have a work around for this.

A consultant is convinced that we don't need to set it up as an application and it can all be done via handlers and route mappings. He conveniently has not provided us with any details though and I have been tasked to implement it.

The best I have achieved was to add a Module Mapping to the Handler Mapping section in IIS. This filters `coolmvcapp/*` with Module `isapimodule` to a virtual directory who's physical path points to our new MVC app. The result is an empty page with a 200 response. Most other combinations I have tried resulted in a variety of errors. (Turns out an empty page is returned without adding the handler mapping - hey ho)

So, is this approach even possible?

I am aware that MVC and webforms can be merged together but for reasons this is something that we want to avoid.

Comment: I hope your "workaround" is having both sites use the same machine key, because otherwise, your "workaround" would be overly complicated and unnecessary.

Comment: I double checked and the machine keys match.  - thanks for the tip!